# How To Make Arrows On The Keyboard Activate JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I wondering how to make it is so that when I click an arrow key, it activates Javascript I've tried some stuff like

```
if (right arrow === pressed){
  }else{
}
```

When that did not work, I tried `document.onkeydown = checkKey;

```
function checkKey(e) {

  e = e || window.event;

  if (e.keyCode == '38') {
      // up arrow
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
      // down arrow
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
   // left arrow
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
     // right arrow
  }
}
```

Which did not work as well so can you help me?

Comment: Do you have an event handler that you are using to call this function, and if so, are you passing the event as the argument?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {

        window.onkeydown = function (event) {
            if (event.key === 'ArrowRight') {
                // Right Arrow pressed
            } else if (event.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
                // Left Arrow pressed
            } else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
                // Up Arrow pressed
            } else if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
                // Down Arrow pressed
            }

        };
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try event.which instead, like this:

```
e = e || window.event;

if (e.which == '38') {
    // up arrow
}
else if (e.which == '40') {
    // down arrow
}
else if (e.which == '37') {
   // left arrow
}
else if (e.which == '39') {
   // right arrow
}
```

Comment: Noting that [`which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) is deprecated and [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `e.which` with whatever key code you want and call the function you want to use:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.which == 37) {
    yourFunctionHere();
  }
});
```

Or if you want to use arrow functions

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if (e.which == 37) {
    yourFunctionHere();
  }
});
```

Comment: Noting that [`which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) is deprecated and [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your "error" is, and you didn't include any code of your actual event listener. That being said, you should try something like these:-

```js
const checkKey = (e = window.event) => {
  if (!event) return;
  if (e.keyCode == '38') {
    // up arrow
  }
  if (e.keyCode == '40') {
    // down arrow
  }
  if (e.keyCode == '37') {
    // left arrow
  }
  if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    // right arrow
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', checkKey);
```

or with jQuery:

```js
const checkKey = (e = window.event) => {
  if (!event) return;
  if (e.keyCode == '38') {
    // up arrow
  }
  if (e.keyCode == '40') {
    // down arrow
  }
  if (e.keyCode == '37') {
    // left arrow
  }
  if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    // right arrow
  }
}

$(document).on('keypress', checkKey);
```

Comment: Noting that [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated and [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) is recommended.